# How do i record the occurances of 'Y' in a txt file in Python 3.2

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to record how many times the letter Y appears in the 6th column of a .txt file and assign that to a variable. How would I go about doing that? Thx in advance!

**.txt file:**

```
119,29/12/15,18:00,Ripley,Magnitude,Y,Magnitude               
120,30/12/15,18:00,Jenkins,Kes,Y,Kes                    
121,31/12/15,18:00,Big Boss,Ingsoc,Y,Ingsoc                
122,01/01/16,18:00,Einstein100,RNGesus,,             
123,02/01/16,18:00,Macho Man,Napoleon Wilson,,               
124,03/01/16,18:00,Dennis,Billy Casper,,
```

I've set the whole file to a variable and have created variables for each column in the file.

```
    NextRecord = data[x]
    Number = NextRecord[0]
    Date = NextRecord[1]
    Time = NextRecord[2]
    P1Nickname = NextRecord[3]
    P2Nickname = NextRecord[4]
    Status = NextRecord[5]
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What are you stuck on?  Is the `Status` variable showing you the value(s) you expect?  What trouble are you having incrementing a counter every time it's `'Y'` inside the loop?

Comment: Status shows me the values I expect but when  I try to find all occurances of Y in the column status it gives me the value 0. I found this but it doesn't work                                                                             
"amountOutstanding = Status.count('Y')"

Comment: Why `Status.count('Y')` instead of `Status == 'Y'`?  Also what are you doing with the `amountOutstanding` variable?  Are you incrementing a global counter somewhere?

Comment: the amountOutstanding variable is just the variable i'm trying to set it to so I can easily recall it#

Comment: Don't you mean "increment"?  If you want a *counter*, you probably want to do something like `if Status == 'Y': amountOutstanding += 1`, right?  (Making sure to set `amountOutstanding = 0` at the beginning.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and [**`sum`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
import csv

with open(filename) as records:
    reader = csv.reader(records)
    print(sum(row[5] == 'Y' for row in reader))
```

Your data is comma separated, and Python has the `csv` module for working with delimited values (could be semicolon separated, etc, as well).

The reader is iterable and yields a row at a time.

I've used the `sum` function which takes an iterable but I've used a generator expression to yield `True` or `False` for each `row` in the file.

The expression `row[5] == 'Y'` evaluates either `True` or `False`. When you give a boolean value to `sum` it converts to an integer and `True` becomes `1`, `False` becomes `0`. We could have written it as:

```
sum(1 for row in reader
    if row[5] == 'Y')
```

This however is slightly different. It filters out only the rows which have `Y` in the 6th column and yields the value `1` for each of those rows. It's subtly different.

Comment: @Daddy: Reads a CSV file like the one you show.  It takes a file object and gives you back an iterator to iterate over the lines.  (Your "txt" file seems to be formatted like a CSV file, so you can probably read it as one.)  See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

You should try using the `csv` module:

```
import csv

counter = 0
with open("data.csv","r") as fi:
    inCsv = csv.reader(fi,delimiter=',')
    for row in inCsv:
        if (row[5].strip() == 'Y'):
            counter += 1
print ("Y count: " + str(counter))
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS should work as expected:

```
noOfY=0
for line in open("thatTextFile.txt"): 
    try: 
        if 'Y' in line.split(',')[5]: noOfY+=1
    except:
        pass
print(noOfY)
```

This gives for the text provided above:

```
3
```

and works even in case of malformed lines in the input text file.